# QByteArray to integer

Tags: qt, arrays

As you may have figured out from the title, I'm having problems converting a `QByteArray` to an integer.

```
 QByteArray buffer = server->read(8192);
 QByteArray q_size = buffer.mid(0, 2);
 int size = q_size.toInt();
```

However, `size` is 0. The `buffer` doesn't receive any ASCII character and I believe the `toInt()` function won't work if it's not an ASCII character. The `int size` should be 37 (0x25), but - as I have said - it's 0.

The `q_size` is `0x2500` (or the other endianness order - `0x0025`).

What's the problem here ? I'm pretty sure `q_size` holds the data I need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't tried this myself to see if it works but it looks from the Qt docs like you want a QDataStream. This supports extracting all the basic C++ types and can be created wth a QByteArray as input.

Comment: This answer and [next answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1261927/721929) conform the complete answer.

Answer (score 30):

Something like this should work, using a data stream to read from the buffer:

```
QDataStream ds(buffer);
short size; // Since the size you're trying to read appears to be 2 bytes
ds >> size;

// You can continue reading more data from the stream here
```

Comment: I already gave your answer a +1. Just wanted to add an example.

Comment: Thought I should mention for those coming here from Google - If you need to convert a little endian array, use `ds.setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian)`

Answer (score 10):

The [`toInt`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html#toInt) method parses a int if the `QByteArray` contains a string with digits. You want to interpret the raw bits as an integer. I don't think there is a method for that in `QByteArray`, so you'll have to construct the value yourself from the single bytes. Probably something like this will work:

```
int size = (static_cast<unsigned int>(q_size[0]) & 0xFF) << 8
         + (static_cast<unsigned int>(q_size[1]) & 0xFF);
```

(Or the other way around, depending on Endianness)

Comment: There's no simpler way ? It would require quite some work if I'd do this not only for WORDs, but for DWORDs, QWORDs, floats, and so on ...

Comment: ohhhhh you're saying the `.to<numberType>` functions for `QByteArray` work if the data is a _string_. I have raw binary data and was pulling my hair out wondering why it wasn't working. Thanks, that is _not_ made clear in the documentation IMO,, but makes perfect sense in hindsight since it takes exactly the same arguments and works the same as the `strtol` family of functions. Silly me.

Answer (score 8):

```
bool ok;
q_size.toHex().toInt(&ok, 16);
```

works for me

Comment: This works when int is smaller than 4 bytes. but it won't work if you want a stream of ints like an array.

Answer (score 1):

I had great problems in converting serial data `(QByteArray)` to integer which was meant to be used as the value for a `Progress Bar`, but solved it in a very simple way:

```
QByteArray data = serial->readall();
QString data2 = tr(data); //converted the byte array to a string
ui->QProgressBar->setValue(data2.toUInt()); //converted the string to an unmarked integer..
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
QByteArray array2;
        array2.reserve(4);
        array2[0] = data[1];
        array2[1] = data[2];
        array2[2] = data[3];
        array2[3] = data[4];

        memcpy(&blockSize, array2, sizeof(int));
```

`data` is a qbytearray, from index = 1 to 4 are array integer.

Answer (score 0):

Create a QDataStream that operates on your QByteArray. Documentation is  [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qdatastream.html#QDataStream-3)

Answer (score 0):

Try `toInt(bool *ok = Q_NULLPTR, int base = 10) const` method of QByteArray Class.

[QByteArray Documentatio: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/QByteArray.html](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/QByteArray.html)